# why does React queryselector thow an error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to hide one part of the component using a id and show the other part using a className. Both have the value of props.id. when I select the element using getElementById it works but when I try to do the same with querySelector for the class it throws an error

I tried if it works if I put the id element into the querySelector but it didn't work either

I want the code to make the id element to show by toggling the class and the class element to disappear

here is the code:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      nazev: "",
      email: "",
      jmeno: "",
      recept: "",
      searchField: "",
      receptyData: { ReceptyData },
      idRecept: ""
    };
  }
  handleSearch = event => {
    this.setState({ searchField: event.target.value });
  };

  handleChange = event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    return console.log(this.state.idRecept);
  };

  callbackFunction = (childData, event) => {
    this.setState({ idRecept: childData });
    event.target.innerHTML = "Postup";
    document.getElementById(`${childData}`).classList.toggle("recept-none");
    document.querySelector(`.${childData}`).classList.toggle("recept-none");
  };

  render() {
    const { nazev, email, jmeno, receptPopis } = this.state;
    const { name, content } = Data;
    const { ReceptyData } = this.state.receptyData;
    const filteredRecepty = ReceptyData.filter(recept =>
      recept.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchField.toLowerCase())
    );
    const recepty = filteredRecepty.map(recept => {
      return (
        <Recept
          key={recept.id}
          receptName={recept.name}
          popis={recept.popis}
          img={recept.img}
          popisTitle="Postup:"
          suroviny={recept.suroviny}
          handleClick={this.handleClick}
          id={recept.id}
          callbackFunction={this.callbackFunction}
          id2={recept.id2}
        />
      );
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            console.log(this.state.idRecept);
          }}
        >
          sdd
        </button>
        <Header />
        <Uvod name={name} content={content} />
        <SearchField
          placeholder="Hledejte recept"
          handleSearch={this.handleSearch}
        />
        <NewReceptyComponent />
        <ReceptyContainer>{recepty}</ReceptyContainer>
        <Form
          nazev={nazev}
          handleChange={this.handleChange}
          jmeno={jmeno}
          email={email}
          receptPopis={receptPopis}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Please include the code and error instead of linking to screenshots